# Efficent way of constructing a matrix with all elements zero except one in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to compute the output error for a neural network for each input by compare output signal and its true output value so I need two matrix to compute this task.

I have output matrix in shape of (n*1) but in the label I just have the index of neuron that should be activated, so I need a matrix in the same shape with all element equal to zero except the one which it's index is equal to the label. I could do that with a function but I wonder is there a built in method in `numpy` python that can do that for me?

Comment: Look into `numpy.in1d`.

Comment: `np.matrix([1 if x == id else 0 for x in results])`?

Comment: @DanielSanchez nah, `__equals__` has all the slow OOP overhead OP probably does not want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that multiple ways using numpy or standard libraries, one way is to create an array of zeros, and set the value corresponding to index as 1.

```
n = len(result)

a = np.zeros((n,)); 
a[id] = 1
```

It probably is going to be the fastest one as well:

```
>> %timeit a = np.zeros((n,)); a[id] = 1
1000000 loops, best of 3: 634 ns per loop
```

Alternatively you can use [numpy.pad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) to pad [ 1 ] array with zeros. But this will almost definitely will be slower due to padding logic.

```
np.lib.pad([1],(id,n-id),'constant', constant_values=(0))
```

As expected order of magnitude slower:

```
>> %timeit np.lib.pad([1],(id,n-id),'constant', constant_values=(0))
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.4 µs per loop
```

And you can try list comprehension as suggested by the comments:

```
results = [7]

np.matrix([1 if x == id else 0 for x in results])
```

But it is much slower than the first method as well:

```
>> %timeit np.matrix([1 if x == id else 0 for x in results])
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.25 µs per loop
```

---

Edit:
But in my opinion, if you want to compute the neural networks error. You should just use [np.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) and compute whether it was successful or not. That error calculation may give you more noise than it is useful. You can make a confusion matrix if you feel your network is prone to similarities.

Answer (score 4):

A few other methods that also seem to be slower than @umutto's above:

```
%timeit a = np.zeros((n,)); a[id] = 1 #umutto's method
The slowest run took 45.34 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 µs per loop
```

Boolean construction:

```
%timeit a = np.arange(n) == id
The slowest run took 13.98 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.76 µs per loop
```

Boolean construction to integer:

```
%timeit a = (np.arange(n) == id).astype(int)
The slowest run took 15.31 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.47 µs per loop
```

List construction:

```
%timeit a = [0]*n; a[id] = 1; a=np.asarray(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.3 µs per loop
```

Using `scipy.sparse`

```
%timeit a = sparse.coo_matrix(([1], ([id],[0])), shape=(n,1))
10000 loops, best of 3: 51.1 µs per loop
```

Now what's actually faster may depend on what's being cached, but it seems like constructing the zero array is probably fastest, especially if you can use `np.zeros_like(result)` instead of `np.zeros(len(result))`

Comment: Ahh boolean construction, very smart.

Answer (score 3):

One liner:

```
x = np.identity(n)[id]
```

Comment: Clearly most elegant way to do this, thanks!